# PDO in command line (cli)

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, pdo, command-line-interface

Today I met a very strange problem, PDO mysql is not working in cli. Here is the output of some commands I used to grab some basic information.

```
charles@vps [~]# php -v
PHP 5.4.24 (cli) (built: Feb  4 2014 12:38:49) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
    with XCache v3.0.3, Copyright (c) 2005-2013, by mOo
    with the ionCube PHP Loader v4.4.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by ionCube Ltd., and
    with Zend Guard Loader v3.3, Copyright (c) 1998-2013, by Zend Technologies
    with XCache Cacher v3.0.3, Copyright (c) 2005-2013, by mOo


charles@vps [~]# php --ri mysql

mysql

MySQL Support => enabled
Active Persistent Links => 0
Active Links => 0
Client API version => 5.1.68
MYSQL_MODULE_TYPE => external
MYSQL_SOCKET => /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
MYSQL_INCLUDE => -I/usr/include/mysql
MYSQL_LIBS => -L/usr/lib64 -lmysqlclient 

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
mysql.allow_persistent => On => On
mysql.max_persistent => Unlimited => Unlimited
mysql.max_links => Unlimited => Unlimited
mysql.default_host => no value => no value
mysql.default_user => no value => no value
mysql.default_password => no value => no value
mysql.default_port => no value => no value
mysql.default_socket => /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock => /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
mysql.connect_timeout => 60 => 60
mysql.trace_mode => Off => Off
mysql.allow_local_infile => On => On


charles@vps [~]# php --ri pdo

PDO

PDO support => enabled
PDO drivers => sqlite, mysql
```

And this is the error I got:

```
charles@xxxxxx.net [~/public_html]# app/Console/cake EmailMarketing.send_campaign_email CAMPAIGN -c 12 -s 23 -t 202
Error: Database connection "Mysql" is missing, or could not be created.
#0 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php(262): Mysql->connect()
#1 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/lib/Cake/Model/ConnectionManager.php(107): DboSource->__construct(Array)
#2 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php(3221): ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default')
#3 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php(1108): Model->setDataSource('default')
#4 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php(3243): Model->setSource('email_marketing...')
#5 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php(2795): Model->getDataSource()
#6 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php(2732): Model->_findCount('before', Array)
#7 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php(2691): Model->buildQuery('count', Array)
#8 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php(2606): Model->find('count', Array)
#9 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/app/Plugin/EmailMarketing/Console/Command/SendCampaignEmailShell.php(181): Model->exists('12')
#10 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/app/Plugin/EmailMarketing/Console/Command/SendCampaignEmailShell.php(62): SendCampaignEmailShell->__validateOption('campaign', Object(EmailMarketingCampaign), Array)
#11 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/lib/Cake/Console/Shell.php(381): SendCampaignEmailShell->startup()
#12 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/lib/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php(200): Shell->runCommand('CAMPAIGN', Array)
#13 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/lib/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php(68): ShellDispatcher->dispatch()
#14 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/app/Console/cake.php(37): ShellDispatcher::run(Array)
```

This is my Cakephp database configuration:

```
public $live = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'login' => 'admin',
    'password' => 'XXXXXXXXXX',
    'database' => 'www',
    'prefix' => '',
    'encoding' => 'utf8',
    'unix_socket' => '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'
);
```

My VPS server is CentOS 6 and my PHP and apache is configured through Easy::Apache v3.24.11.
The PDO mysql seems OK, but it just refuses to work.

I have spent my whole day struggling with it, please help me with this, maybe there is something obvious and I just cannot see it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not very proficient with CakePHP but you call `getDataSource('default')` while your DB is `live`.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I put the following code in shell and I still get the same error. It seems the data source is there, but "Mysql" is missing. I don't fully understand what the error message is trying to say, :(.

    `App::uses('ConnectionManager', 'Model');
    $db = ConnectionManager::getDataSource("live");
    $this->log(print_r($db));`

Comment: I finally found the issue. I just knew that there must be something obvious and I just cannot see it. In database config file, I have multiple datasource configured. And I only use the URL to determine which datasource to use. But CLI don't have a URL, so the configuration is not correctly picked. And that is why it is not work.